# Is it possible to add an Office 365 Group to a SharePoint Group using Power Automate (Flow)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, office-365-groups

I am trying to automate a site creation process and I need to be able to add an Office 365 group to a new SharePoint group. I have managed to create the SharePoint group from flow using a few articles I came across online, but I am trying to add an Office 365 group to the new SharePoint group.

I found ways to add a single user to the group, so that works fine. But I want to add a whole Office 365 group. I tried doing a couple different things, but it didn't work out. Has anyone done this before? I would think its possible. Any resources that may be helpful? The last attempt I did, using the HTTPS action in Power Automate and REST services, I got an error saying the user does not exists. I guess that means I am not using the right REST endpoint. I will do some more exploration there. I will update this answer if I get it working.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to add an Office 365 Group to a SharePoint Group. Office 365 group is for Office 365 tenant. It is outside of SharePoint service and its structure is in Azure AD. While Sharepoint group is scoped in a site.

They're 2 concepts, you can only add users to SharePoint groups.